# Remove auto start from Shimmer effect programmatically (Using Shimmer-Android by Facebook)

Tags: android

I am using Shimmer-Android library by Facebook for a Shimmer Effect.

But I would like to start the effect programmatically, as my `ShimmerFrameLayout` is added programmatically (not in XML)

`val shimmerFrameLayout = ShimmerFrameLayout(context)`

I can't access the attribute `auto_start` from code, do you have any ideas how I can prevent the animation from auto starting ?

Comment: shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer()

Comment: I don't want to start it, I want to prevent it from autostarting

Comment: are you sure??, because I don't do anything, and it is started by default

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android/blob/master/shimmer/src/main/java/com/facebook/shimmer/Shimmer.java#L73 Do you have access to the Shimmer object? If so you could disable it through the setAutoStart method https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android/blob/master/shimmer/src/main/java/com/facebook/shimmer/Shimmer.java#L369

Comment: Yes I have seen this, I tried  ```val shimmerFrameLayout = ShimmerFrameLayout(context)
        shimmerFrameLayout.setShimmer(Shimmer())```
but they say cannot access 'init' it is public/*package*/ in 'Shimmer'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a builder for this and it has also all the setters for all the other attributes!

```
shimmerFrameLayout.setShimmer(Shimmer.AlphaHighlightBuilder().setAutoStart(false).build())
```

Comment: Perfect ! this is exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you